# Javascript array append

Tags: javascript, append

how could I append new item into one array..

I have the following javascript code to initialize 2 variables:

```
var timeStamps = [];
var totalscore = [];
```

and in the for loop, I want to do something like this:

```
timeStamps.append(timestamp)
totalscore.append(score)
```

timestamp is string type, score is double type

thanks

Comment: Array.prototype.push() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in js you can use `.push(object)` to add.  Javascript doesn't care about types.

```
timestamps.push(object);
```

or

```
timeStamps[timeStamps.length] = object;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timeStamps.push(timestamp);
```

Use push

Some documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

```
timeStamps.push(timestamp);
totalscore.push(score);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `timeStamps.push(timestamp);`

Edit: looks like I'm late to the party